# Call js function after div is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a div element which is loaded after a click on a radio button.

Need to hide a part of the div after it is loaded.

```
$(function($) {
  $('.div_element').on('load', function() {
    $('.textbox').hide();
  });
});
```

The above code doesn't work. I need to trigger a function after the div is shown on the page.

Comment: A `<div>` doesn’t “load”. Do you want to call a function as soon as the `<div>` is in the DOM? Search for Mutation Observers. If the `<div>` isn’t in the DOM, then you can’t bind an event listener to it.

Comment: Can you add woking snippet of your code? That would be easy and faster to debug

Comment: @Xufox Yes, the div is shown on the page after radio button is clicked. I then need to say hide one of the textbox in the div that is loaded.

Comment: @phpblogger what is your code to hide?

Comment: @KiranShahi Updated the question. The duplicate link has the first param as "some url" - I dont have anything to use on that place, is there any other possibility?

Comment: Just hide a part of the div the same time it created.

Answer (score 2):

Although it may not be good solution but you can check in an interval if the div exist, if it is then you can do further:

```js
$(() => {
  const checkDiv = setInterval(() => {
    if($('.div_element').length > 0) {    // it's better to use id instead of the class as selector
      clearInterval(checkDiv);
      // more action here
    } 
  }, 100); // check after 100ms every time
});
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. but as expected takes more time to load the main div :-(. Sad that there is no onload event for the element which can just act based on the visibility of the div

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would go about it. This is using vanilla JavaScript but it can easily be adapted to use jQuery.

The idea is to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I hope it helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>DOM MUTATION OBSERVERS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <form name="radios">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="maleRadio" checked> Male
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="femaleRadio"> Female
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="otherRadio"> Other
    </form>

    <!-- This div will be displayed when the radio button whose value is female is clicked. -->
    <div id="femaleDiv" style="display: none">
        <p>The textbox should be below...</p>
        <input type="text" id="textToHide">
    </div>

    <script>
        // After the document loads...
        document.onload = function () {
            // Attach an onclick listener to the radio buttons.
            var radios = document.forms["radios"].elements["gender"];
            for (var i = 0, max = radios.length; i < max; i++) {
                radios[i].onclick = function (event) {
                    var radio = event.target || event.srcElement;
                    console.log(radio.name);
                    if (radio.value === "female") {
                        document.getElementById("female").style.display = "block"
                    }
                }
            }

            // Get the div whose change in attributes we are interested in.
            var targetNode = document.getElementById("femaleDiv");

            // Set the mutation observer to only listen to attribute mutations
            var config = { attributes: true };

            // This will be called when a mutation has been observed
            var callback = function(mutationsList) {
                for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
                    if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
                        console.log(mutation);
                        console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
                        if (targetNode.style.display == "block") {
                            document.getElementById("textToHide").style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            // Create the observer
            var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

            // Start observing
            observer.observe(targetNode, config);

            // Uncomment this to stop observing at at the right place.
            // observer.disconnect();
        } ();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Div is initialized

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       var textBox="<input type='text' class='textbox'>";
       $(".textboxContainer").html(textBox);   
       
       var divNew="<div class='div_element'>DIV to Load</div>";
       $(".domNewDiv").html(divNew); 
       
          var divNew1="<div class='div_element'>DIV to Load 2</div>";
       $(".domNewDiv").html(divNew1); 
});


$(".div_element").init( function(){
    $('.textboxContainer').find('.textbox').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='textboxContainer'></div>
<div class='domNewDiv'>
</div>
```

Comment: Already tried this - it doesn't work after the div is loaded. Just checks on page load if the div is present on not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding, you need to perform an action on clicking of a radio button. This is where your code should start.

```
$("input[name='YOUR_BUTOTN_NAME_GOES_HERE']").click(function(){
//I suggest to use a same class for both the radio buttons you want to click as this will effect for all the radio buttons
    console.log('You clicked radio!');
    var checkDivLength = setInterval(function(){
   if($('.div_element').length > 0) {

      //Hide your element
      $('.textbox').hide();
      clearInterval(checkDivLength);
   } 
   }, 100);
});
```

Please note that  in this line `"$("input[name='YOUR_BUTOTN_NAME_GOES_HERE']").click(function(){"` you need to give the name attribute which you have used in your code. Eg `<input type="radio" name="sample" value="test">` then your code should be `"$("input[name='sample']").click(function(){"`

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke it using " () ", when the event calls:

```
$(function($) {
  $('.div_element').on('load', function() {
    $('.textbox').hide();
  }());
});
```